# Create this shape with css polygon clippath

Tags: css, angular, nativescript, native, polygon

I have created this shape using https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ but I need to give it rounded edges. Similar to the picture[image]

Comment: Please show relevant HTML and CSS in your question. What research have you done?

Comment: @GRD Nativescript doesn't allow :before so only with clipath because I need to add an animation to it.